# `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting started with ruby on rails, but facing a lot of issues setting up a new blog from ruby tutorials.

I had installed ruby 2.3.0 using `rubyenv` on my Mac El Capitan. But soon after I ran into namespace conflicts and errors. I solved them one by one but now when I run

`bin/rails generate controller welcome index`

on the new blog, I get -

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
```

Why does it show 2.0.0 when I've installed 2.3.0?

Stuff I've tried:

`$ sudo  gem update --system`

`$ export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH"`

`$ echo $GEM_HOME`
`<returns blank>`

`$which -a ruby`

```
/Users/shubhamkanodia/.rbenv/shims/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

`rbenv versions`

```
  system
* 2.3.0 (set by /Users/shubhamkanodia/.rbenv/version)
```

Comment: Try `bundle install --binstubs` then generate the controller

Comment: @RAJ I get `Unknown switches '--binstub'` when i run it

Comment: Does your project specify a Ruby version in a `.ruby-version` file, or in the `Gemfile`?

Comment: @Drenmi I seem to have a `.rubyversion` file in my project folder with value `2.3.0`. I don't remember which command I executed for that though.

Comment: @user3210476 - from the error `Unknown switches '--binstub'` it seems that you missed the 's' at the commandline (bundle install --binstub**s**)

Comment: @UriAgassi My bad... it works now... But why did i need to do it? And do I have to do it every time I create a project?

Comment: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/wiki/Understanding-binstubs

Answer (score 4):

maybe fix `bundle exec rake rails:update:bin`